# PrimeNg Turbo Table p-table lazy load scroll event

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-turbotable

I am implementing primeNG turbo table. I am able to implement it but while implementing lazy loading. iam not been able to get scroll event. How to get scroll event in my method. Below is what i have tried.

```
<p-table #dt 
          dataKey="id"
          [columns]="columns" 
          [value]="gridData" 
          [scrollable]="true" 
          sortMode="single"
          scrollHeight="500px" 
          *ngIf="isDataLoading" 
          (onLazyLoad)="loadDataOnScroll($event)" 
          [lazy]="true" 
          [rows]="25" 
          [totalRecords]="recordTotal"
          [(selection)]="selectedRows" 
          (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)" 
          (onRowUnselect)="onRowUnselect($event)" 
          (onHeaderCheckboxToggle)="onHeaderCheckboxToggle($event)"
          selectionMode="multiple"
          [virtualScroll]="true" >

</p-table>
```

method to get lazyload event.

```
loadDataOnScroll1(event: LazyLoadEvent) {

          let firstTime: boolean;
          let onScroll: boolean;
          let onSort: boolean;
          let globalSearch: boolean;

          console.log(event);
          if (event.globalFilter == null && !event.filters.hasOwnProperty('global') &&
               event.hasOwnProperty('sortField') && event.sortField == undefined) {
               firstTime = true;
               console.log('user iscoming for the first time ');
          } else if (event.globalFilter != null && event.globalFilter.length > 0 && event.filters.hasOwnProperty('global') &&
               !event.hasOwnProperty('sortField')) {
               globalSearch = true;
               console.log('user is doing only global search');
          } else if (event.hasOwnProperty('sortField') && event.sortField != undefined && event.globalFilter == null && !event.filters.hasOwnProperty('global')) {
               onSort = true;
               console.log('user is doing sorting');
          } else if (event.hasOwnProperty('sortField') && event.globalFilter != null && event.filters.hasOwnProperty('global')) {
               globalSearch = true;
               onSort = true;
               console.log('user is doing global search along with sort');
          } else {
               console.log('user is doing onscroll so do increment for page number');
               // here we need to take entire event and get all possible values to call
               // get api and update grid data
               // 
          }

     }
```

I am able to get sort , filter , global search event but i am not been able to get scroll event.I want to get the event and call my service to get paginated data.

Thanks.

Comment: Bad Tagging... PrimeFaces != PrimeNG, please correct

Comment: @Kukeltje then why does they say PrimeNg on their officiate website.https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table

Comment: Because when they started with the PrimeFaces **PRODUCT** they registered the primefaces.org url. When they also adopted the hyped client-side javascript frameworks, they abused the same url instead of registring primeng.org or whatver. Just because something is on the same url does not make it related to a product with that same name. If you just READ the info of the tags you use, you should see it is a product as wel. Reverted your edit!

Comment: @Kukeltje can you please help me in lazy load event , to get scroll event

Comment: No, since I'm no PrimeNG user but a PrimeFaces user

Answer (score 1):

i fix this problem with a trick. i set the totalRecords as a large number or a number much larger than your current data(e.g. the current data's length is 500, set the totalRecords as 1000), then the lazyloading will be triggered on each scroll

Comment: but how will you get to know the scroll event ?

Comment: Seems both sort and scroll will trigger onLazyLoad. Is there a way to distinguish them?